# What if EntityManager is not closed due to Exception?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, entitymanager

What happens if an `EntityManager` in a JavaSE app optained through `EntityManagerFactory` is not closed, eg due to any `Exception` that terminate the method before `em.close()` is reached?
Will em be closed automatically after a timeout?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have `em.close()` in a `finally` block in that case?

Comment: the question is if I need to neccessarily?

Comment: It may or may not affect the application negatively, but in what world is not closing a resource in a finally a good design?